# how to disable bottom navigation for some fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Hello I have added a bottom navigation in main activity and rest all of the layouts are fragments now I have a login fragment that I don't want to show the bottom navigation and I don't even want to include bottom navigation to each fragment separately, is there any method where I can disable bottom navigation in some fragments like login fragment

> if you need more reference please tell me i will update the question

**Main_Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Deque<Integer> integerDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(4);
    boolean flag = true;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
        integerDeque.push(R.id.nav_home);
        loadFragments(new Home_Fragment());
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                item -> {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    if (integerDeque.contains(id)) {
                        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
                            integerDeque.size();
                            if (flag) {
                                integerDeque.addFirst(R.id.nav_home);
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        integerDeque.remove(id);
                    }
                    integerDeque.push(id);
                    loadFragments(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
                    return false;
                }
        );

    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    private Fragment getFragment(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                return new Home_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_following:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                return new Following_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_upload:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                return new Upload_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
                return new Notification_Fragment();
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(4).setChecked(true);
                return new Profile_Fragment();
        }
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        return new Home_Fragment();
    }

    public void loadFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        integerDeque.pop();
        if (!integerDeque.isEmpty()) {
            loadFragments(getFragment(integerDeque.peek()));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1** // adedd login_fragment according to the answer but its not working

**Login_Fragment.java**

```
    public class Login_Fragment extends Fragment {
        @Nullable
        @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**:- OK the method given in the answer is working but when I go to the previous fragment the bottom nav diapered for all the fragments or I say for entire app there is no bottom nav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do bellow in your fragment:

```
BottomNavigationView navBar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
navBar.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
```

or

```
 public class Login_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: hey brother i have tried it but it is not working , i have update the question please can you check it

Comment: hey brother it is not working as well it is showing unreachable statement and also i declare the bottomnavigationview in mainactivity as public

Comment: you have to set it before return, nothing after return will be reached

Comment: hey brother i have tried this and it works fine till i go back to the previous or anyother fragment the bootomnavigation is gone for all

Answer (score 2):

> Hello I have added a bottom navigation in main activity and rest all
> of the layouts are fragments now I have a login fragment that I don't
> want to show the bottom navigation and I don't even want to include
> bottom navigation to each fragment separately ,is there any method
> where I can disable bottom navigation in some fragments like login
> fragment

So, you don't want to handle that on every fragments, but only on the fragments that you want to make the BottomNavigationView hidden.

@Ali A. Jalil provided part of the answer for hiding the `BottomNavigationView` while accessing the login fragment; the same way you can show it again, when this fragment is destroyed in the opposite fragment lifecycle method to that you hide it in; i.e. You've hidden it in `onCreateView()`, then you need to show it in `onDestroyView()`.

```
 public class Login_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
    }   
}
```

This way you have the same state in terms of `BottomNavigationView` visibility when you exit the login fragment as you entered it.